# Cinnamon hotkeys suddenly remapped - where are they defined?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, cinnamon

I'm using Cinnamon with Ubuntu 15.04 and I've been setting my hotkeys in `Keyboard > Shortcut`, for example Ctrl-Alt-t is mapped to "Launch Terminal":

[image: Screenshot of Launch terminal hotkey.]

I also have "Super-L" mapped to "Lock screen":

[image: Screenshot of Lock Screen hotkey]

This was working as expected for a day or so, and all of a sudden the keys are remapped in some weird way. `Ctrl+Alt+t` opens up a new Firefox window for some reason (no matter what has focus). `Super+l` opens this "Ubuntu Desktop Guide" window I've never seen before:

[image: Ubuntu Desktop Guide]

Hotkeys work as expected in Unity.

**Edit**
Per A.B.'s suggestion, I found that the keyboard shortcuts in settings are set in `/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/media-keys/terminal`, but those settings *are* accurate, and the problem persists:

[image: screensaver line dconf-editor]

**Edit 2**:
As mysteriously as it arrived, this problem has gone away suddenly a few days (and many, many restarts) later.  I'm still interested in strategies for determining exactly what is receiving a hotkey, though (and plus I have to imagine this will come back one day).

Comment: Install `sudo apt-get install dconf-cli dconf-editor`, start `dconf watch /` in a terminal and change a shortcut. Look at the output in your terminal and see the path. Open the path in `dconf-editor` and change all shortcuts to the default values.